# Memory exhausted error coming while creating catalogrule with category

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4, save, catalog-rules

I have around 50 categories. When I save the catalogrule without selecting the categories it gets saved correctly. But when I save along with selecting the category it display memory exhausted error. The exhausted error coming after 65 queries at the point when implode function is executed in Profiler.

If I set the category in already created catalogrule, it works fine.

What is the behaviour of Magento2

```
60  7.8370  799786680   Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Interceptor->getAttributeObject( ) ...\Interceptor.php:50
61  7.8370  799786680   Magento\Eav\Model\Config->getAttribute( )   ...\AbstractProduct.php:152
62  7.8370  799971432   Magento\Eav\Model\Config->getEntityType( )  ...\Config.php:499
63  7.8370  799971888   Magento\Framework\Profiler::start( )    ...\Config.php:389
64  7.8370  799971888   Magento\Framework\Profiler::_getTimerId( )  ...\Profiler.php:268
65  7.8370  799971888   implode ( ) ...\Profiler.php:153
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an issue with Magento of slow saving catalog rule.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13378

This patch happens to be the solution of my problem.